# SED Linux command to replace in exactly in a line

Tags: regex, sed

I have the following batch

```
#! /bin/bash
PATTERN1="MACRO"
PATTERN2="HI"
sed -e "s/${PATTERN1}/${PATTERN2}/g" config.conf
```

So, the content of the file config.conf is

```
ABC
   DEF
   ERF MACRO
   ERR
MACRO
```

So, the output of the command is:

```
ABC
   DEF
   ERF HI
   ERR
HI
```

but the desired output is

```
ABC
   DEF
   ERF MACRO
   ERR
HI
```

In other words, I need to replace the pattern only with the exactly match per line, without spaces or other words in the same line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add `^` and `$` to the pattern you want to do **exact** match

with your example: you can either do:

```
 sed -e "s/^${PATTERN1}$/${PATTERN2}/g" ...
```

or use your original sed line, modify the `PATTERN1`:

```
PATTERN1="^MACRO$"
```

Comment: the answer is bad, because...?

Comment: @FredrikPihl thank you. I think the answer works for OP's input... didn't understand the downvote. Hope the downvoter could leave some tips/comments so that I can learn.

Comment: you can add that `g` is not needed in this case

Comment: @Kent +1, I don't think downvoter wants you to learn. You know too much already!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
awk '$0==p {$0=r}8' p="${PATTERN1}" r="${PATTERN2}" file
```

Comment: I would quote the shell variable part.